# Efficiency of $\hat{\theta}_{MLE}$ from $\operatorname{Beta}(\theta,1)$

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I am working on a problem which asks me to discuss the efficiency of the MLE $\hat{\theta}$ given that $X_1,\ldots,X_n \sim_{iid} \operatorname{Beta}(\theta,1) $.

I was able to deduce that

$$\hat{\theta} = \frac{n}{-\sum_{i=1}^n \ln X_i}$$

and that the Rao-Cramer Lower Bound is

$$RCLB=\frac{\theta^2}{n}$$.

Since $E[\hat{\theta}]=\frac{n}{n-1}\theta$ the MLE is asymptotically  unbiased, and I found that

$$Var[\hat{\theta}]= \frac{n^2\theta^2}{(n-1)^2(n-2)}$$.

What bothers me a little is that I was able to proove that the coefficient of $\theta^2$ is a value that is larger than $1 \over n$ when $1.57 < n$ so I see that this variance is indeed larger than the RCLB.

However, the fact that when $n=1$ and $n=2$ is undefined makes me a bit uneasy.

Is there something that needs to be considered in these cases or is there an assumption that I am missing?

Comment: I don't remember may things from statistics, but I wonder about something... for example, for $n=1$ the $\hat{\theta} = \frac{n}{-\sum_{i=1}^n \ln X_i}$ is equal to $\frac{1}{-\ln X_1} = \frac{1}{Y} = Z$, where $Y \sim Exponential(\theta)$ and $Z$ is from Inverse exponential distribution. From what I heard, expected value for $Z$ doesn't exist, so the variance is indeed undefined. But not sure how to approach the main task correctly here.

Comment: Thank you.  I am now learning that there are situations where variances may not exist.  It is quite interesting, but until the time comes I will just leave it as is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact distribution of the MLE is $$\hat \theta \sim \operatorname{InverseGamma}(n,n\theta)$$  with PDF $$f_{\hat \theta}(t) = \frac{(n\theta)^n e^{-n\theta/t}}{t^{n+1} \Gamma(n)}, \quad t > 0.$$  The variance and expectation you computed are correct.  Note that when $n = 1$, this distribution is heavy-tailed, in the sense that for large $t$, $f_{\hat \theta}(t) \sim 1/t^2$, which is like a Cauchy distribution (or equivalently Student's $t$ with $1$ degree of freedom).  Similarly, when $n = 2$, the distribution of $\hat \theta$ has a finite expectation but infinite variance, because for large $t$, $f_{\hat \theta}(t) \sim 1/t^3$.

I do not see why there should be any concern that $$\operatorname{Var}[\hat \theta] > \theta^2/n.$$  The Cramér-Rao lower bound is not always attainable, even for "best" unbiased estimators.  What would be concerning is if an unbiased estimator were to have a variance that is smaller than such a lower bound as this would violate the theorem.

Comment: Thank you.  I was not aware of the fact that there are infinite variances or situations where RCLB cannot be attained.  Although there is much more for me to learn in statistics, this was very helpful for now.

Answer (score 1):

If your definition of efficiency is that the estimator must attain the Rao-Cramer lower bound, then yes the MLE is not efficient. Even the minimum variance unbiased estimator of $\theta$, namely $(1-n)/\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \ln X_i$ does not attain the lower bound, but it remains the most efficient estimator of $\theta$ within the unbiased class.

When you are talking about efficiency, you are more often than not concerned with increasing sample size, so cases like $n=1$ or $n=2$ can be safely ignored.

Now efficiency $(\mathrm{e})$ of your MLE is the ratio of the Rao-Cramer bound and variance of the MLE, i.e. $\mathrm{e}=\frac{(n-1)^2(n-2)}{n^3}$, which converges to $1$. Or if you consider the asymptotic variance of the MLE, then $\mathrm{e}\approx 1$ for large $n$. So either way the MLE is asymptotically efficient.

Comment: Thank you.  I am going to conclude my answer as not efficient since we are concerned about the situation where n is large.  It also should work for small ns, but I do not have enough to understand that situation so I will just leave it as that.